# Java NetBeans: El logaritmo base 10 no me acepta valores decimales

Tags: java, importación, static

De antemano les agradezco su ayuda.

Estoy tratando de calcular el pH en java, pero no me acepta valores decimales, no se exactamente cual sea el error, pero es posible que este mal declarada la clase `Math`, por la web encontré un sitio que mencionaba que debía agregar la forma `(double a)`, quedando

```
import static java.lang.Math.log10(double ph);
```

pero NetBeans me indicaba que había error.

Este es mi codigo:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.Math.log10;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);
        double ih;
        System.out.println("Escribe un valor para los iones hidronio:");
        ih=entrada.nextDouble();
            double ph=(log10(ih))*-1;
            System.out.println("El pH correspondiente es igual a: "+ph);
    }     
}
```

Comment: ¿Cómo estás metiendo los valores decimales, separando con comas o con puntos?

Comment: a que error te refiers,tu codigo si copila

Comment: @ordago te agradezco, realmente eso era, introducia los numeros con punto, pero nunca antes habia intentado con la coma.

Answer (score 0):

Ayudaría si pasas el error que te reporta, aún así, el error ocurre en

```
double ph=(log10(ih))*-1;
```

Por otro lado en caso de aceptar **double** se me ocurre probar creando la variable estática
[image: Extraído de la api de java]